# How to write a column to file without duplicates in R and order alphabetically

Tags: r

I am trying to write to a csv file with `write.table` but from what I've read it has limited capabilities. I am using the following command.

```
write.table(s$Nomen, "table.csv", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

which exports a datasheet consisting of a single column (as I like it). However, that column contains a lot of duplicate values. I would like to remove duplicates and order the column alphabetically.

For example, if this is s$Nomen:

```
Nomen
------
archer
sent
chocolate
banana
arbitrary
column
paste
paste
knowledge
zen
banana
sent
surprise
```

The output should be:

```
arbitrary
archer
banana
chocolate
column
knowledge
paste
sent
surprise
zen
```

I'm assuming `sort.list` comes in handy, but I don't know how to remove the duplicates.

**Note** the data in the original column `s$Nomen` should *not* be altered! So I don't want to re-order the actual column, but I want to re-order the output.

Comment: May be `sort(unique(s$Nomen))` or `sort(s$Nomen[!duplicated(s$Nomen)])`

Comment: Also note that there is a `write.csv` function, although `write.table` should work just fine.

Comment: @nrussell - you jinxed me!

Comment: @akrun Thanks, that worked. Could you post it as an answer? So I can accept it.

Comment: I don't understand why this gets down-voted. I am a beginner in R, I googled my ass off for this and I tried a number of things. What else was I supposed to do?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I find it curious that you expect a data export function to extract unique values and sort them. That's not the job of such functions. A google search for "R remove duplicates" and "R sort" should have been enlightening.

Comment: @Roland I appreciate the response. I did do a google search, that's how I came to `sort.list`. I didn't find anything to remove duplicates as easily as with `unique` though. The main problem was fitting all pieces together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try either `unique` or `duplicated` from `base R`

```
sort(unique(s$Nomen))
```

Or

```
sort(s$Nomen[!duplicated(s$Nomen)])
```